# Amazon ElastiCache High Availability

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, high-availability, failover, amazon-elasticache

I am using Amazon ElastiCache for Redis. I am not using Redis for caching, but storing very important key which is used in every transaction hitting to my server. So if ElastiCache instance fails I can't wait for 3-6 minutes to start another instance. According to FAQs on Amazon site, its says that Multi-AZ will failover automatically but it may takes few minutes that is 3-6 minutes to get new instance up and running which is not acceptable for my server. Is there any higher plan which supports 100% uptime with failover in few seconds and not minutes. I couldn't find anything on Amazon site. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: ElastiCache is only really intended as a cache, hence the name. If you want a highly available version of Redis as a Service on AWS, with data persistence, I would recommend looking into the "Redis Cloud" service from Redislabs. Otherwise you might need to look into building your own Redis servers on EC2.

Comment: I tested with Redis Cloud but it seems to take more time. Where ElastiCache takes around 15-20ms, redis cloud takes 300-400ms to get the response. This is vast difference for me. My server which is uses ElastiCache is on EC2 whereas I tested redis cloud from my local machine. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Viddesh that doesn't sound right - I recommend contacting our awesome support team with that and they'll sort it out in less than a millisecond :)